# Monaco Editor: set cursor position within a provideOnTypeFormattingEdits

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

I am using the following code to auto close an xml tag when typing the '>' of an openening tag.

Everything works fine so far. But i want to set the cursor inbetween the tags. Instead the cursor will be at the end of the closing tag.

`<myTag>[cursor should be here]</myTag> [cursor is here]`

```
        monaco.languages.registerOnTypeFormattingEditProvider('xml', {
            autoFormatTriggerCharacters: ['>'],
            provideOnTypeFormattingEdits: (model: any, position: any, ch: any) => {
                if (ch === '>') {
                    const codePre = model.getValueInRange({
                        startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                        startColumn: 1,
                        endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                        endColumn: position.column,
                    });

                    const match = codePre.match(/.*<(\w+)>$/);
                    if (match) {
                        const tag = match[1];
                        const closingTag = `</${tag}>`;
                        const edit = {
                            range: {
                                startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                                startColumn: position.column,
                                endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                                endColumn: position.column,
                            },
                            text: `${closingTag}`,
                        };

                        return [edit];
                    }
                }

                return [];
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than returning the edits from `provideOnTypeFormattingEdits` you can call [editor.executeEdits](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/editor.ICodeEditor.html#executeEdits). This function allows an optional parameter `endCursorState` to be passed which contains details where you want the cursor to end up (in the form of an array of [Selection](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/classes/Selection.html)).

As you just want to cursor to be between the 2 tags, you can get the cursor position (`editor.getSelection()`) in your `provideOnTypeFormattingEdits` function, and pass this into `editor.executeEdits`:

```
// Get the current selection (used to set the cursor position after inserting the closing tag)
const sel = editor.getSelection();
// Call executeEdits rather than returning the edits
// This allows us to pass a Selection[] which updates the cursor position afterwards
editor.executeEdits('', [edit], [sel]);
```

The full `provideOnTypeFormattingEdits` function becomes:

```
provideOnTypeFormattingEdits: (model, position, ch) => {
    if (ch === '>') {
        const codePre = model.getValueInRange({
            startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
            startColumn: 1,
            endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
            endColumn: position.column,
        });

        const match = codePre.match(/.*<(\w+)>$/);
        if (match) {
            const tag = match[1];
            const closingTag = `</${tag}>`;
            const edit = {
                range: {
                    startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                    startColumn: position.column,
                    endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                    endColumn: position.column,
                },
                text: `${closingTag}`,
            };

            // Get the current selection (used to set the cursor position after inserting the closing tag)
            const sel = editor.getSelection();
            // Call executeEdits rather than returning the edits
            // This allows us to pass a Selection[] which updates the cursor position afterwards
            editor.executeEdits('', [edit], [sel]);
        }
    }

    return [];
},
```

There's a working demo [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.44.0#XQAAAAIUBQAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw7pXQXsfv0Gi3IkXOlGFgqVBo1gXcVBJuu7943Nu4-lpRcjNAjJqt4YQC9DLaLenGZMmWdl5IE2roygFOdUKq56yQPHdubPdNOvl426eaWIOK1SN2tYPmEpDbj3IKBd0fAQqrfz6eZDzLZORU4VyqblnpI-O0PQNFyQFUf4F7VuARzyX1eupj841vFNcc9vMJUS028yDeTnromCyoJ2x95P6tTUB2qaMmF0ZODrKJ1ZXtFUXWLNxRyS6mpDeCqO-SjUSUfU8I1-avsxs1H-8LPSeZv1Zhn_LeI7O5YsFGSGTVO5_vYFgIhZF9xU-aqV7UBrH9e45CjxlmHV77rOl35BKHWyjKOZIQsiGHfZJdBI5GYOnEdaWIdezIHHy_7mDpATIEGYtfXu6uj7_lql8oxy-wVzraP5i9iP1pPBKmDzQ3qwGWtjd6YN7YA7FORWMXJpDmUoGnGfCCI6ZAzoez-L88cUewKIQWgBm7jtCrPBigvFW2gNMYBLfITJ9OAQ2IHrwxrdcJUA2NyrfaxD5_Bc42l5_OQD6h7CfXi4OxR_FoMjPBodMChJE6cw1AefsoVYNnPCsXIxxLDV47ltYKSajcV83yo9pPfN47zuJzIzrVxQ901WLmOu6j9Bml5nWH_3bkllloorlp3WK09YPmMjQ2h-jSHE9RTRlzvvxQjur4C2MsHjWaWck83qZczUi2dE5PI6A7uTyXqsnqfU40N_QQ_692ym_SPzwCHt62RpnKQLnqJjVCwR6Obw0ggGhjEVAy82uuIN86Ng3umkup9t6He6XXqaiB16m1BP99vhEY) on the Monaco Playground.